# geom_density2d plot population data in r

Tags: r, dictionary, population

I really need some help. I would like create an plot in R, but i do not know how should weight the point. I used this code below, and the point is equivalent. I would like is one of much bigger than another.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

Cau_map <- get_map(location='Caucasus', maptype="satellite", zoom = 5)

Cau <- data.frame(
lat = c(41.1057, 38.2968),
lon = c(44.2105, 47.1744),
data = c(52, 7)
)




ggmap(Cau_map, extent='device') +
  geom_density2d(data=Cau, aes(x=lon, y=lat), color = "red", size=.3) +
  stat_density2d(data=Cau, aes(x=lon, y=lat,  fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.08, bins = 6, geom = 'polygon')+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "red4", guide=FALSE) + scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1), guide = FALSE)
```

This is what I got:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger than the other". Which point, what size?

Comment: I have got two points. The first "size or weight or something" is 52 value and a second is 7 value. I would like represent the bigger value (52) is dilute toward the smaller value (7).

Comment: This is hardly reproducible and not very clear. Please further elaborate your problem (see some [tips here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and what the solution is expected to look like.

Comment: Sorry! Now I have editing that! Now you can try the code. I wolud like ditribution map (for exemple: http://www.eupedia.com/europe/maps_Y-DNA_haplogroups.shtml), but i need some help about the process.